# Unable to access library function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am noob in codeigniter. I used an external class file for getting the length of an audio file. I put the file in application/libarary directory. After googling and reading documentation I tried two things for accessing the libarary function which I have mentioned under the codeigniter problem.

**Working Demo from the External Library File**

```
 require ('classAudioFile.php');
 $filename = "40f11852c2314cdf1d06308f07de3b1c.mp3";
 $AF = new AudioFile;
 $AF->loadFile($filename);
 echo $AF->wave_length;
```

**CodeIgniter Problem**

```
 $filename = "./uploads/audio_files/347f21502e9b27fac4707b07c3c15eb7.mp3";
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $CI->load->library('AudioFile');
 $CI->AudioFile->loadFile($filename);

 $filename = "./uploads/audio_files/347f21502e9b27fac4707b07c3c15eb7.mp3";
 $this->load->library('AudioFile');
 $this->AudioFile->loadFile($filename);
```

I am getting **Call to a member function loadFile() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\webcartz\application\modules\playlist\controllers\admin.php on line 149  this is the actuall error.**. can any body please help. I tried to call it in both Controller and View file.

Comment: Have you set prefix in the configuration ?

Comment: Do you get any Code Igniter error, like "Could not load library"? Also, please check your error message, as it doesn't make much sense. I think you forgot some words there :)

Comment: @Teneff Sorry I dont know what is prefix..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to normalize everything try the following:

1. the `AudioFile.php` you put in the library folder, make the file name all lower case, like `audiofile.php`.  if it is called `classAudioFile.php`, rename it to simply `audiofile.php`
2. check that there is a class `AudioFile` in `audiofile.php`.
3. change the `AudioFile` in the `load->library` to all lowercase
4. change the `AudioFile` in the `$this->AudioFile->` to all lowercase
5. if it still does not work change the name of the class (not the file) to `Audiofile`, capital A, lower case f.

Also, there should be an default - no parameter constructor in the class `Audiofile`. like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // you can put some code here if you want
}
```

Comment: It worked....wow.....thanks....so the naming of classes and files was the problem.